# How do I set up port forwarding on Huawei router

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I have question about setting up port forwarding.

I want to do port forwarding as suggested on this [troubleshooting guides](https://support.ubisoft.com/en-gb/faqs/000025832/Connection-issue-in-The-Division-on-PC/).

```
Below are the ports you need for The Division:

Game ports:
TCP: 27015, 51000, 55000 to 55999, 56000 to 56999
UDP: 33000 to 33499
Uplay ports:
TCP: 443, 14000
```

This is because I always got disconnected when playing the games.

But when I enter my router (provided by the ISP), there are no port forwarding features listed. I only see this features:

[image]

I see that port forwarding sometimes called virtual server? CMIIW, but I'm not sure what it is called for this router.

Answer (score 0):

You should find it in IPv4 Port Mapping